# Default UIView using Segmented Control?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using a `UISegmentControl` to switch between 2 `UIViews`, one to select a user and the second to show information about that user.

The issue I am having is the `UIView` that shows initially when navigating to this page is dependant on the placement in the storyboard hierarchy.

I would like the "selectionView" to always be the default screen that comes up when navigating to this page.

The segment tab itself is correct with `selectedSegmentIndex = 0` and works as expected once I switch between them, but the only I've been able to correct this issue is to change the position of the views in the storyboard.

How would I be able to do this programmatically?

```
import UIKit

@IBOutlet weak var segmentController: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func segmentIndexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: selectionView.hidden = false; infoView.hidden = true
    case 1: selectionView.hidden = true; infoView.hidden = false
    default: break
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var selectionView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var infoView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    segmentController.setTitle("Select User", forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
    segmentController.setTitle("User Info", forSegmentAtIndex: 1)

    segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` Add below code

```
override func viewDidload
{
   ......
   selectionView.hidden = false
   infoView.hidden = true
   .......

}
```

Comment: Haha oh wow... I thought I tried this already, but I guess it was one of those "its so obvious I missed it" kind of things. Thank you